# Issue using Remote Desktop Manager mRemoteNG and its freeware alternatives

Tags: ssh, runtime-error, remote-server, remote-desktop, rdp

I use `Remote Desktop Manager` i.e  `mRemoteNG` which stopped working on my Windows and does not work despite reinstallation and other fixes.

While I would like to know freeware / opensource alternatives to mRemoteNG which i can use for RDP and SSH connection below is elaboration of my issue.

I used to connect to Windows and Linux hosts and organize my server list using mRemoteNG.

Below is the Current Error launching mRemoteNG and it crashes right after it starts.

```
An item with the same key has already been added.

at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   at mRemoteNG.App.Update.UpdateFile.FromString(String content)
   at mRemoteNG.App.Update.UpdateFile..ctor(String content)
   at mRemoteNG.App.Update.UpdateInfo.FromString(String input)
   at mRemoteNG.App.Update.AppUpdater.GetUpdateInfo()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

OS: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.19045.0
mRemoteNG Version: 1.77.1.27713
Edition: Portable
Cmd line args:
```

[image]

I tried deleting the `confCons.xml` and the <user_home>/Appdata/Local and Roaming folders for mRemoteNG and launching the software.

The same software when copied to another Windows host works fine.

Kindly suggest.